# How to make quick info section visible to roles in Sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have a `Community Admin` role, inherited by

- `sitecore\Sitecore Client Securing`
- `sitecore\Sitecore Client Users`
- `sitecore\Sitecore Client Publishing`
- `sitecore\Sitecore Client Designing`
- `sitecore\Sitecore Client Authoring`

And I want to make quick info section visible to only `Community Admins` in Sitecore 8.

I tried using the checkbox `Quick Info` in Application options button in Top left corner of the content editor. This helps, but it is user specific that I can make this option show/hide to a particular user not for all the users who have Community Admin role.

How can I make this `Quick Info` section visible to all `Community Admin` users?

Answer (score 4):

There is no user interface for specifying which users / roles can / cannot see Quick Info section. The only setting I am aware of is **Sitecore top left (Hamburger) button** --> **Application options** --> **Content editor** --> **Quick info section**; that is just a checkbox applied for currently logged user only.

Does custom code works out for you? There was a previous SO question on [How to Hide Quick Info Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30348656/hide-quick-info-in-sitecore-through-code)

You can slightly modify the code from that post in order to check if user is in roles with `Sitecore.Context.User.IsInRole` method and that would work.

Answer (score 0):

You Can also enable the quick info section by navigating to View -> Standard Fields and check the 'Standard Field' checkbox.See below screenshot.

[image]